# RSpec is failing when it shouldn't. Why?

Tags: rspec, sinatra

I'm building a very small Sinatra API, and today I started writing tests for it. I'm using RSpec and FactoryGirl.

I have a User model, In the controller I check if the email of the user that is signing up is already saved or not. If saved I return a 402 if not I create the user and return a 200. To test this, I'm doing a POST to the `users` route with the same params two times, in the first one I check for `last_response.should be_ok` because the DB is empty so I can create the user, and then I have another test that POST to `users` route with the same params as the one before but expecting a `last_response.should_not be_ok` and I'm getting a 200! so the test fails!!

This is my Sinatra route:

```
post '/users' do
    user = User.where(email: params[:email]).first

    if !user
        user = User.create(email: params[:username], password_not_hashed: params[:password])
        halt 200, {user:user}.to_json
    end 

    halt 409, {error:"user already exists"}.to_json
end
```

And this is my test:

```
describe 'Create User' do
    include Rack::Test::Methods
    params = {}
    params['password'] = "username"
    params['username'] = "username@username.com"

    it "should create a user" do 
        post '/users', params
        last_response.should be_ok
    end

    it "should fail to create a user because its duplicate user" do 
        post '/users', params
        last_response.should_not be_ok
    end
end
```

And I'm getting a fail because the response of the last test is 200. I've printed the `params` and the `last_response` with `pp` and this is what I got:

Params:

```
{"password"=>"username", "username"=>"username@username.com"}
```

last_response

```
@block=nil,
@body=["{\"user\":{\"id\":null,\"email\":\"username@username.com\"}}"],
@body_string=nil,
@chunked=false,
@errors="",
@header=
    {"Content-Type"=>"text/html;charset=utf-8",
    "Content-Length"=>"52",
    "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1;    mode=block",
    "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff",
    "X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN"},
    @length=52,
    @original_headers=
    {"Content-Type"=>"text/html;charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Length"=>"52",
        "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1;    mode=block",
        "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff",
        "X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN"},
    @status=200,
```

Any idea?!?! It's driving me crazy!

EDIT:

Just added an active record validation (`validates_uniqueness_of :email`) and in the output of my test I get the following:

```
Failure/Error: post '/users', params
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
Validation failed: Email has already been taken
```

So, that means that there is an already created user with that email, so I still don't understand why the test fails, and the route to create a user always gets inside the `if !user`

Here is the output of the code coverage: 
[image]

Crazy... I'm so lost!

EDIT:

Also I have an `after all` rspec hook but that shouldn't be importat as it's only run after all the test:

```
after :all do
   ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.each(&:delete_all)
end
```

Comment: What about changing your conditional at line 14? I've been playing with that !user condition in irb and I wonder if it consistently evaluates the way we would expect. I am still not sure. What about using "if user.nil?" instead? That seems a little more precise.

Comment: same problem... changed it to user.nil? and is still going in!

Comment: What happened when you added print statements or breakpoints? Were you able to check the state of the database during test execution?

Comment: I added some prints in the controller to check if the 'user' was nil or not and it was nil. Maybe is something related to sqlite? (The db I'm using in the test env... I don't know what else to try, already spent too many ours I hope someone realize what's happening... I want to know!! Haha

Comment: By design, your test database should not preserve data between tests. If it did, you could end up with all sorts of weird hidden data dependencies in your tests. You can pressed you test db using a rake db:prepare task to populate your test db, call a factory, create a before statement in your spec, or do something cheesy like my suggestion below to create the user before you invoke the API again. So, your tests appear to be working  correctly since you are not prepping your db before test execution. I wonder how you got the active record validation to work . . .

Comment: I clean the db using rspec after all hook to have a clean db in next tests run. I'm using factory girl and all the other tests are passing fine. Active record validation finds the user created by the previous test and raises an exception, but why it pases the if from the controller?  WEIRD!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the detailed question -- this is really nicely put together. I have a suspicion that your prior post to /user is not preserving the new user in your test db between tests. Have you tried putting in a print statement in your second call to post to make sure that your test db contains a user? That would look something like this:

```
it "should fail to create a user because its duplicate user" do 
    puts User.where(email: params[:email]).first
    post '/users', params
    last_response.should_not be_ok
end
```

You might also want to install pry and put a breakpoint in your test. You can read more about pry here: https://github.com/pry/pry. This would let you check the state of your test db as your code executes. Once pry is installed, you could add an interactive break to your code like this:

```
require 'pry'

<other test business happens>


it "should fail to create a user because its duplicate user" do 
    binding.pry
    post '/users', params
    last_response.should_not be_ok
end
```

If your test db does indeed not preserve the data between posts to /user, you might try something like this for your second test to add the user before you attempt to post:

```
it "should fail to create a user because its duplicate user" do 
    User.create(email: params[:username], password_not_hashed: params[:password])
    post '/users', params
    last_response.should_not be_ok
end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I added an active record validation of uniqueness and I get an active record error, so something weird is happening... the user is created in the first call, but I don't know why it's not found in the second call in the database... weird